# How can I validate/make a matrix field required on the front-end?

Tags: matrix, frontend, registration

I am displaying inputs on the front-end of my form that are populating a matrix within the CP.

Overall everything is working fine. The problem I am having is validation. I've got the field marked as required, but it seems leaving the fields empty still passes validation.

```
    ....

    <input type="hidden" name="fields[myMatrix][new1][type]" value="myField">
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[myMatrix][new1][enabled]" value="1">

    ...

    {{ account is defined and account ? errorList(account.getErrors('myMatrix')) }}
```

Whenever I comment these fields out, I get the validation message that the field is required. I believe it has something to do with those hidden input(s) a value. But, if I take those out, the fields do not populate the input in the CP.

How can I show the fields on the front-end and still show the error message?